# insert id from two tables by search

Tags: php, mysql

I try to associate the ID with users and administrators where administrators can search for users when the administrator is logged in.

The search function works and it displays the right content.

However, when the administrator is to connect a user, only the administrator's ID is stored in the database, the user's id is not retrieved from the form.

Any suggestions?

```
$seartch=$_POST["seartch"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `u_fName` LIKE '%$seartch%' OR u_lName LIKE '%$seartch%' ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("error.");
$queryResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($queryResults == 0) {
  print("<br> no seartch");
} else {
    for ($i=1; $i <=$queryResults; $i++) {
      $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      $uidU = $row["u_id"];
      $first=$row["u_fName"];
      $last=$row["u_lName"];

      echo "<form method='POST' action='' role='form'>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <br>
            <td name='id' id='id' value='$uidU'> $first $last
            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-outline-success' name='registrate'>add</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </form>";
    }
  }
}

if (isset($_POST['registrate'])) {

  $uidU=$_POST["id"];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO `connection` (`u_id`, `admin_id`) VALUES ('$uidU', '$uidAdm');";
  $result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql) or die ("error");
  print("<br> saved");
  exit();
}
```

Comment: the complete html is wrong and will not validate..

Comment: I suggest that you do not concatenate values from $_POST directly into an SQL string and then execute it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**First issue** - your HTML is invalid, there is no reason to create several instances of a form in the loop, so in your WHILE loop, you need to remove the  tags and replace it outside of the loop.

**Second issue** - you're using table related tags but aren't actually creating a table. So I've removed that from the WHILE loop.

Because you're using the `<td>` tag incorrectly. `<td>` does not have a value param, whereas an `<input>` does. Try the following:

```
echo "$first $last
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-outline-success' name='registrate'>add</button>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$uidU'>";
```

This uses a hidden input to pass the value to your logic.

Comment: OP is creating a ton of extra form tags in a loop, I guess I should address that.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry Adam, I am new on stackoverflow, I guess I checked it when I accepted the answer, sorry about that.